# Who is the employee that Steve Jobs fired?

Tags: character, historical-accuracy, biopic, jobs

In [Jobs (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2357129/) there is a scene whereby Steve Jobs fires an employee for disagreeing with him on "fonts":

Who is the employee who disagreed with Steve Jobs on the "font" issue and got fired?

Is this part of the movie (that is based on Steve Jobs real life) an event that happened or was it added for drama? If so can someone name the real person referenced?

Comment: Your question is about a biography and since you are asking about real life events and not if they have a basis on the movie it makes it close enough to a trivia question that isn't important. However I edited it just a little I hope that keeps it open for you. Welcome to our site by the way.

Comment: I downvoted it as unimportant trivia. Admittedly it's borderline, but even with the edit I don't see how knowing the name of the person enhances the movie, even if that person ended up being Bill Gates.

Comment: As of 2019 the movie is no longer available due to copyright claims.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This scene was meant to put a spotlight on Jobs' darker side, but the event never really happened.  In a fact check, this scene was specifically mentioned:

> Take the movie's font scene. At an all-hands meeting, an employee dares to question Jobs’s choice of “adding pretty fonts” on the Lisa
>   computer, the forerunner to the Macintosh, causing Jobs to fire him
>   with a cinematic “Get out!” But this event didn’t actually happen. In
>   reality, Steve Jobs hired a typeface designer, Susan Kare, and got to
>   work convincing the rest of Apple’s executives that fonts were a
>   worthwhile way to spend their money and time. It was an act of soft
>   diplomacy, not a unilateral diktat.

Source: [Vulture.com](http://www.vulture.com/2013/08/jobs-fact-check-truth-versus-fiction.html)